# Error undefined, php/mysql

Tags: php

Hola me dan un error en la siguiente linea para que no lo esta haciendo correctamente:

```
$registro2 = $registro->fetchAll();
```

Codigo php completo:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$id = $_POST['id-prod'];
$proceso = $_POST['pro'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$precio_uni = $_POST['precio-uni'];
$precio_dis = $_POST['precio-dis'];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');
//VERIFICAMOS EL PROCESO
$query='';
require_once 'conexion.php';
$database_connection = database_connect();

switch($proceso){
    case 'Registro':
        $database_connection->query("INSERT INTO productos (nomb_prod, tipo_prod, precio_unit, precio_dist, fecha_reg)VALUES('$nombre','$tipo','$precio_uni','$precio_dis', '$fecha')");
    break;

    case 'Edicion':
        $database_connection->query("UPDATE productos SET nomb_prod = '$nombre', tipo_prod = '$tipo', precio_unit = '$precio_uni', precio_dist = '$precio_dis' WHERE id_prod = '$id'");
    break;
}


//ACTUALIZAMOS LOS REGISTROS Y LOS OBTENEMOS

$registro = $database_connection->query("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id_prod ASC");

//CREAMOS NUESTRA VISTA Y LA DEVOLVEMOS AL AJAX

echo '<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th width="300">Nombre</th>
                <th width="200">Tipo</th>
                <th width="150">Precio Unitario</th>
                <th width="150">Precio Distribuidor</th>
                <th width="50">Opciones</th>
            </tr>';
$registro2 = $registro->fetchAll();
foreach ($registro2 as $registro){
    echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$registro2['nomb_prod'].'</td>
                <td>'.$registro2['tipo_prod'].'</td>
                <td>S/. '.$registro2['precio_unit'].'</td>
                <td>S/. '.$registro2['precio_dist'].'</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:editarProducto('.$registro2['id_prod'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a> <a href="javascript:eliminarProducto('.$registro2['id_prod'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></a></td>
                </tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

El resto me funciona bien. es un registro en jquery con php y paginacion.
Basicamente lo que me pasa que cuando muestro con el foreach me da el siguiente error, si muestro un campo no pasa nada pero si muestro varios me da esto:

> Notice: Undefined index: nombre_prod in
>   C:\wamp\www\www\registro\php\agrega_producto.php on line 42

Comment: Date cuenta que estás duplicando el nombre de la variable `$registro`. Cambia el nombre del alias en el forearch. ¿Ya probaste con un `fetch_assoc`?

Comment: gracias por ese detalle se me paso el problema esque cuando hago echo '<tr><th>'.$regit['nom_prod'].'</th>'.'<th>'.$regit['tipo_prod'].'</th></tr>'; me da el error undefined sin embargo cuando añado la clave principal no que es id_prod. No se el motivo exactamente. fetch_assoc lo incluyo?

Comment: no lo intente la verdad pero no creo el error es claro. Notice: Undefined index: nom_prod

Comment: Verifica primero que trae realmente el array $registro2 con un var_dump, es decir, si realmente trae nom_prod o tiene otro nombre porque por algún motivo no lo trae en el array y por eso te da el undefined. Otra cosa que vi en tu ejemplo es que en el foreach usas $registro2['nomb_prod'] mientras que el mensaje de error es  Undefined index: nombre_prod y no nomb_prod. Revisa con mucha atención tu código.

Comment: esto lo que obtengo C:\wamp\www\www\registro\php\agrega_producto.php:14:
object(PDOStatement)[2]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * FROM productos' (length=23)

Answer (score 1):

En la documentación del [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) puedes ver que el formato es:

```
foreach (expresión_array as $valor) {
    sentencias usando $valor
```

Pero en tu código estás haciendo

```
foreach (expresión_array as $valor) {
    sentencias usando expresión_array
```

Que es incorrecto, porque `$registro2` (tu `expresión_array`) no contiene los parámetros que intentas acceder; es `$registro` (tu `$valor`) el que los contiene y el que debes utilizar dentro del `foreach`. En lugar de hacer esto:

```
            <td>'.$registro2['nomb_prod'].'</td>
            <td>'.$registro2['tipo_prod'].'</td>
            <td>S/. '.$registro2['precio_unit'].'</td>
            <td>S/. '.$registro2['precio_dist'].'</td>
```

Deberías estar haciendo esto otro:

```
            <td>'.$registro['nomb_prod'].'</td>
            <td>'.$registro['tipo_prod'].'</td>
            <td>S/. '.$registro['precio_unit'].'</td>
            <td>S/. '.$registro['precio_dist'].'</td>
```

> Aparte de eso, tu código presenta vulnerabilidades de seguridad graves y puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de dinámicas.

Comment: no actualice esa parte en stackoverflow pero esque hago eso mismo y me da el siguiente error Notice: Undefined index: nom_prod in C:\wamp\www\www\registro\php\agrega_producto.php on line 44
Call Stack y esto lo que puse  foreach ($registro2 as $regit){
    
    echo '<tr><th>'.$regit['id_prod'].'</th>'.'<th>'.$regit['nom_prod'].'</th></tr>';
       
            
            
}

Comment: Prueba a poner dentro del foreach algo como `var_dump($regit);`; eso te permitirá ver que datos y estructura contiene cada elemento que recuperas. Incluso si está vacío.

Comment: C:\wamp\www\www\registro\php\agrega_producto.php:47:
array (size=6)
  'id_prod' => int 1
  'nomb_prod' => string 'Atun' (length=4)
  'tipo_prod' => string 'Enlatado' (length=8)
  'precio_unit' => float 6
  'precio_dist' => float 5
  'fecha_reg' => string '2011-05-01' (length=10)

Comment: es decir el campo existe pero sin embargo me da este error Notice: Undefined index: nom_prod in C:\wamp\www\www\registro\php\agrega_producto.php on line 46

Comment: el problema es el campo nom_prod

Comment: el campo estaba mal escrito simplemente solucionado